# Is it possible to make a Photo App within AppClips?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, apple-appclips

I want to make an AppClip for my photo filter app, that takes photos and videos.
And o Im thinking of building a very quick appclip experience where you can open a camera and play with a few filters, take a photo or record a video and save to your Camera Roll.

From what I read at Apple's website.
There are certain Frameworks limitations, in which I dont see AVFoundation, to access the camera/microphone. But I do see 'PHOTOS' framework.. which might be a problem if I want the user to save to Camera Roll.

> App Clips are limited to 10MB in size.
>
> The following frameworks are not available to App Clips: CallKit,
> CareKit, CloudKit, HealthKit, HomeKit, ResearchKit, SensorKit, and
> Speech. Using any of these frameworks in an App Clip does not result
> in compile-time errors, but their APIs return values that indicate
> unavailability, empty data, or error codes at runtime.
>
> App clips cannot perform a background activity, such as background
> networking with URLSession or maintain Bluetooth connections when the
> App Clip is not in use.
>
> To protect user data, Apple App Clips cannot access: Motion and
> fitness data, Apple Music and Media, Data from apps like Contacts,
> Files, Messages, Reminders, and Photos.
>
> An App Clip cannot share data with any other app, except its
> corresponding full app.
>
> An Important limitation is location access. App Clips cannot request
> continuous location access.

Has anyone done any AppClip where you access the camera and or save content to the Camera Roll ?

Comment: I haven't. More, I considered if an App Clip is a good thing for my photo editing apps, which sounds like what you are thinking. While it *could maybe* be possible, I decided it flies in the face of what Apple thinks an App Clip is. To me? Beyond the 10MB size, **you** mention "play with a few filters", and saving the result, both of which feels wrong. I get that App Clips are the *new* gold rush, but technically you **still** need (a) the app and (b) more functionality than most would expect without a purchase. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue at least you can export photo using sharing options, like UIActivityViewController, it will prompt the user to save the images wherever the user wants, including camera roll.